# Sublime Text 2 cannot open due to pylint

Tags: sublimetext2, pylint

Once my ST2 crashed and cannot open. The dialog shows:

Pylinter could not automatically determined the path to `lint.py`. Please provide one in the settings file using the `pylint_path` variable. NOTE: If you are using a Virtualenv, the problem might be resolved by launching Sublime Text from correct Virtualenv.

I reinstalled ST2 but still cannot open it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I reinstall pylint for my Python 2.7 by using easy-install. Then my ST2 works well.

Comment: `pip install pylint` did it for me. Thanks!